# Не появляется задний фон

Tags: jquery, браузер

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').css('background-image', 'url(/images/1.jpg)')
});
```

Не открывается картинка,в консоле пишет:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND 1.jpg:1

В чём проблема? В `images` есть эта картинка, `html` файл там же, все есть, но не получается.

Comment: а данный скрипт где расположен?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно корректно написать путь до картинки.  Откройте полученную ссылку в браузере, подкорректируйте путь и внесите изменения в код.

Например картинка расположена в папке `c:/site/image/bg.jpg` а вы пытаетесь открыть `c:/image/bg.jpg` Анализируйте, исправляйте, ищите где ошибка в пути.

Возможно вам нужно будет дописать путь в `url("image/" + imgUrl)`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 

  var imgUrl = "https://wallpaperbrowse.com/media/images/3848765-wallpaper-images-download.jpg";
  //var imgUrl = "c:/site/image/bg.jpg";
  
  $("body").css("background-image", "url('"+imgUrl+"')")

});
```

```css
html, body{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
body{
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Возможно адресс фотографии указан не верно. Возможно тегу body не задана ширина и высота. А вообще это очень дико задавать стили через JS